# Cases I do not have to unwrap a Swift optional?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm confused why the `label.text = textField.text` line works even though `textField.text` is an optional. Generally I'd write it as:

```
if let text2 = textField.text {
    label.text = text2
}
```

The above code works fine but why does the `label.text = textField.text` work fine too? I thought it's a must to unwrap optionals? When must I use the `if let` syntax and when do I not have to?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label.text = ""
    }

    @IBAction func setTextButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        label.text = textField.text
    }

    @IBAction func clearTextButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        textField.text = ""
        label.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: You can assign an optional to an optional; you can assign a non-optional to an optional, but you cannot assign an optional to a non-optional.  The 3rd case is when you must unwrap.

Answer (score 3):

`UILabel text` is an optional `String`.

`UITextField text` is an optional `String`.

An optional can accept an optional or a non-optional.

A non-optional can only accept a non-optional.

You only need to unwrap an optional when you need a non-optional from it.

Answer (score 2):

As vacawama pointed out:

> You can assign an optional to an optional; you can assign a
>   non-optional to an optional, but you cannot assign an optional to a
>   non-optional.

So you need to unwrap the optional if you wanted to assign it to a non-optional.

And to unwrap an optional, it's always safer to use `if let` statement, which extracts the non-optional version of the optional and assign it to a variable for further usage.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not familiar with implicitly unwrapped optionals.

`label` is an implicitly unwrapped `UILabel`, and `textField` is an implicitly unwrapped `UITextField`

That's what the `!` in the declaration

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
```

means.

Thus, it's legal to assign things to it without unwrapping it:

```
label.text = "some string"
```

However, that's not necessarily **safe**. If `label` is nil, that code will crash.

If `label` was a normal optional:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel?
```

you'd have to use code like this:

```
label?.text = "some string"
```

Xcode sets up outlets as implicitly unwrapped optionals by default, since if an outlet is not connected, it's good to have your code crash so you know something is wrong.

Another part of this is that it's ok to compare 2 optionals with each other:

If you have

```
var a: Int? 
var b: Int?
```

It's legal to test `a == b`. (Put formally, `Optionals` are `Equatable`.) That expression will evaluate to true if both are `nil`, or if both contain the same value. You'll get false if one is `nil` and the other contains a value, or if both contain different values.

(Note that optionals are not `Comparable` however. You could not use `a < b`, for example, since it's not define if `nil > 0` or `nil < 0`.)

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the two outlets being implicitly unwrapped optionals. The question is about the fact that the `text` properties of `UILabel` and `UITextField` are optional.

Comment: I guess you're right that the OP was asking about the text properties, but an expression like `label.text` is not legal with "regular" optionals, and the OP's code included several such expression that would not compile if `label` and `textField` were "regular" optionals. Thus I think covering implicitly unwrapped optionals is important.